# Multiple entity managers (using different data sources for multiple db connections) in a single processor under a particular step: Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring-batch

I am trying to use 2 entity managers in my Spring Batch project in the processor, one for reading and another for persisting data in the db. 
The code is as follows

```
@StepScope
@ComponentScan("com.airtel.billreminder.model")
@Transactional
@Slf4j
public class MyItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<VoltSiMaster,VoltSiMaster>{

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="voltuser")
    EntityManager emvoltUser;

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="voltreporting")
    EntityManager emvoltUserReporting;

    @Value("#{jobParameters['notificationNumber']}")
    public Long notificationNumber;

    @Value("#{jobParameters['dayBeforeNotificationValue']}")
    public Long dayBeforeNotificationValue;

    @Value("#{jobParameters['firstReminderBeforeDueDate']}")
    public Long firstReminderBeforeDueDate;

    private ReminderHistory reminderHistory;

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public VoltSiMaster process(VoltSiMaster voltSiMaster) throws Exception {
        log.info("Inside Processor");
        perpareNotifications(voltSiMaster,notificationNumber,dayBeforeNotificationValue);
        return voltSiMaster;
    }

    @Transactional
    private void perpareNotifications(VoltSiMaster siMaster, long notificationNumber,long dayBeforeNotificationValue) {                 
        try {
                /*business logic*/
                if(notificationNumber>0)
                {
                    txnDone = checkIsTxnAlreadyDone(siMaster);
                }               
                if (!txnDone) {

                    String[] communincationTypesArray = communincationTypes.split(Pattern.quote("|"));
                    for (String communincationType : communincationTypesArray) {
                        log.info("Before sending notification");
                        if(siMaster.getAmount()>0)
                        sendNotification(notificationNumber,siMaster,
                                customerResponse, communincationType);
                        else
                        log.info("Amount is "+ siMaster.getBillerName() +" "+siMaster.getAmount()+"so not sending notification");
                    } 
                }
                else
                {
                    log.info("User has Already Paid Bill so no need to send notification");
                }                   
        }
    }

    private boolean checkIsTxnAlreadyDone(VoltSiMaster siMaster) {  
        String sqlString = "select * from "+Schemas.VOLT_USER_REPORTING+".volt_txn_log  where txn_date_time >= (?1-"+firstReminderBeforeDueDate+")  and CUSTOM_COL_3=?2 and uc_id=?3";
        try {
            Query txnCheckQuery = emvoltUserReporting.createNativeQuery(sqlString, VoltTxnLog.class);
            txnCheckQuery.setParameter(1, siMaster.getBillDueDate());
            txnCheckQuery.setParameter(2, siMaster.getReference1());
            txnCheckQuery.setParameter(3, siMaster.getUcId());
            log.info("Query to fire : {} " + txnCheckQuery.toString());
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            List<VoltTxnLog> resultList = txnCheckQuery.getResultList();
            if (resultList != null) {
                if (resultList.size() > 0)
                {
                    for(VoltTxnLog vtxnlog: resultList)
                    {
                        if(vtxnlog.getTxnStatus().equals("0") || vtxnlog.getTxnStatus().equals("2"))
                            return true;                            
                    }
                }
                else
                    return false;
            } else
                return false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.info("Error: "+e.getMessage());
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Transactional
    private void sendNotification(long notificationNumber,VoltSiMaster siMaster,CusDetResponse customerResponse, String communincationType) {
        /*business logic*/
        emvoltUser.persist(reminderHistory);
        emvoltUser.flush();
    }

}
```

Config file for first entity manager:

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnBean;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnMissingBean;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "voltEntityManagerFactory",
transactionManagerRef = "voltTransactionManager", basePackages = {"com.airtel.billreminder.model.voltUser"})
public class VoltUserDbConfig { 

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "voltDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "volt.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Primary
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="voltuser")
    @Bean(name = "voltEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean barEntityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("voltDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return builder.dataSource(dataSource).packages("com.airtel.billreminder.model.voltUser").persistenceUnit("voltuser")
                .build();
    }

    @Primary
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = "transactionManager")
    @ConditionalOnBean(DataSource.class)
    @Bean(name = "voltTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager barTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("voltEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory barEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(barEntityManagerFactory);
    }

}
```

Config file for second entity manager:

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnBean;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnMissingBean;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "voltReportingEntityManagerFactory",
transactionManagerRef = "voltReportingTransactionManager", basePackages = {"com.airtel.billreminder.model.voltUserReporting"})
public class VoltUserReportingDbConfig { 

    @Bean(name = "voltReportingDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "voltreporting.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="voltreporting")
    @Bean(name = "voltReportingEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean barEntityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("voltReportingDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return builder.dataSource(dataSource).packages("com.airtel.billreminder.model.voltUserReporting").persistenceUnit("voltreporting")
                .build();
    }

    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = "transactionManager")
    @ConditionalOnBean(DataSource.class)
    @Bean(name = "voltReportingTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager barTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("voltReportingEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory barEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(barEntityManagerFactory);
    }

}
```

Spring batch initializes its own transaction manager which i handled using @ConditionalOnMissingBean annotation because it was not creating my custom entity manager previously

Now running this code gives me following exception at emvoltUser.flush() even when i m using @Transactional which should handle the transaction by itself

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.checkTransactionNeeded(SessionImpl.java:3505)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1427)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1423)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor56.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:350)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy109.flush(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor56.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:305)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy109.flush(Unknown Source)
at com.airtel.billreminder.notificationStep.MyItemProcessor.sendNotification(MyItemProcessor.java:233)
at com.airtel.billreminder.notificationStep.MyItemProcessor.perpareNotifications(MyItemProcessor.java:135)
at com.airtel.billreminder.notificationStep.MyItemProcessor.process(MyItemProcessor.java:112)
at com.airtel.billreminder.notificationStep.MyItemProcessor.process(MyItemProcessor.java:58)
at com.airtel.billreminder.notificationStep.MyItemProcessor$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$29bbf641.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
at com.airtel.billreminder.notificationStep.MyItemProcessor$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7ddd0f69.process(<generated>)
at com.airtel.billreminder.notificationStep.MyItemProcessor$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$29bbf641.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:136)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
at com.airtel.billreminder.notificationStep.MyItemProcessor$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ab91a70.process(<generated>)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doProcess(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:126)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.transform(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:303)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:202)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:75)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:272)
at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:81)
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375)
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:200)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:66)
at
org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:136)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:308)
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:141)
at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:134)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor66.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:197)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy112.run(Unknown Source)
at com.airtel.billreminder.config.BatchConfig.notificationJobLauncher(BatchConfig.java:343)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor75.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84)
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have been stuck at this problem for 2 days now and I searched every possible article or previous answers but none could give me the hint to handle 2 entity managers under single processor pointing to different db connections.

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: Can you please first explain what are you trying to achieve without referring to Spring Batch before going in the details of your attempted solution?

Comment: Basically i have 2 separate db and i have read(R) tasks for one db and R/W tasks for the second one. To achieve this, i have configured 2 entity managers

Answer (score 1):

You are using `@Transactional` on your processor which will already be executed in the scope of a transaction driven by Spring Batch. Spring Batch handles the transaction management for you so you don't need to make the processor or writer transactional. I recommend to remove this annotation from your processor and let it participate in the transaction driven by the framework.

The error `javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress` means your `JpaTransactionManager` is not being used. You need to either:

- make one of your batch configuration classes extend `DefaultBatchConfigurer` and override `getTransactionManager` by returning the JPA transaction manager
- or add a bean of type `BatchConfigurer` in your context and make it return the `JpaTransactionManager`

Here is an example:

```
@Bean
public BatchConfigurer batchConfigurer(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
   return new DefaultBatchConfigurer() {
       @Override
       public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
          return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
       }
   };
}
```

Note that this requires Spring Batch v4.1+ to work properly.